# How to check if i landed on the same coordinate three times?

Tags: python

I have a game that when I land on a place, which is a coordinate,it checks it and replaces that coordinate with an object sort out thing. I'm struggling to do it please can any of you help me.
Please can any of you help me.THANKS :) t

Comment: You need to be more specific and provide more context of the code you posted. Only these three lines will make it hard to help you.

Comment: I have tried to give you more detail @migg. If you need more to help me just say.

Comment: dont worry dhruv got it work,Thanks for the help @Dhruv

Answer (score 1):

you can use tuple as key to store x and y axis and put counter on values

```
>>> a = {(0,1):1, (0,2):2}
>>> a
{(0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2}
>>> a[(0,1)]
1
>>> a.get((0,2), None)
2
```

Whenever player landed on some coordinate update in dict if its 1st time, else check the value is greater than 3 or not. if not increment the value and update the dict.

Comment: Why not use a real [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) then.

Comment: Thanks for help @Hackaholic.Is there any way to use a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: yea sure just use list instead of tuple, tuple will be good choice as tuple is immutable and list is not .

Comment: @TheUnknown You won't be able to use a list. Lists are mutable and can't be used as keys.

Comment: What can you use to add to tuples, like append for lists @Dhruv

Comment: @TheUnknown Why do you need to add values to the coordinate tuples? You can'y.

Comment: yeah but how would I add the coordinates which are randomly generated into the tuple @Dhruv Sorry if I am being stupid

Comment: @TheUnknown I'll write an answer to explain how.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to note down how many times each coordinate was visited. You can use a dictionary. A dictionary is a container which holds a particular item for every particular key. Its denoted by curly braces.

Let the dictionary be `d`.

`d = {}`

To set an item,

`d[(x, y)] = 1`

Here `(x,y)` is a tuple. You are confused between what tuples and dictionaries are.

You'll do this for the first time. For the next time you'll have to increase it by one which you can do by:

`d[(x, y)] += 1`

Comment: Thanks @Dhruv I will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: I have tried using this method but it doesnt work very well with my code.Thanks for your help, if you have any other way plz suggest @Dhruv

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with the new code? I'll try to find the errors.